# Create CountDown Days of inserting and update record in database

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I need some help , I Have a form to insert data in table using SQL Server ,
What i want to do a timer or countdown for 2 day from the day that i inserted a record from this form and after this 2 days if this record did not updated the program send mail for me that this record is still not updated .

lets say example , user1 use this form to insert invoice data but not all the invoice columns because there is another User should revision the entry data and update the invoice by inserting the other columns what i want to do right now is create a countdown timer for 2 days , if the user1 insert the invoice today the countdown start for this invoice and count 2 days if the user2 did not update the invoice the program do something by send in the admin mail tell him that user1 add invoice which ID is # in date ....... and the user2 did not update the  this invoice .

do i need to add column new column in database that record the timer for each invoice or what im confused of how thinking about this what is the idea and how can i create this countdown for each invoice .

Comment: A database stores data - you arent going to be able to store a running timer.  So add a Datetime column that your code can examine and act on

Answer (score 0):

The database is a data store, not a scheduler. You should add a column with a "reminder date" and have some code run on a schedule which retrieves any rows which have a "reminder date" past due, then send the mail accordingly.

Comment: Yes I All ready have 3 columns in database table in this invoice row date of creation and this hold the date of invoice creation

Comment: the Invoice row is InvoiceID , username1,CreationDate,Username2,RevisionDate1,Username3,RevisionDate2 the invoice complete in 3 steps creation - revision - Accounts how can i make creation a counter or timer limited 2 days after the day of creation if RevisionDate1 not set then send email , is there a solution to make this and so on from Step 2 to step 3